# break statement in loop not working

Tags: ruby, anemone

I am new to anemone gem. I have written the following code:

```
    anemone.on_every_page do |page|
      if page.url.to_s.match(/\-ad$/)
        unless page.url.to_s.match("restaurant|hotel")
          p "not useful url: #{page.url}"
          count += 1
          if count == 5
            break
          end
          next
        else
          count=0
        end
      end
    end
```

Here in break statement I am getting the **localjumperror: break from proc-closure**. I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: You're not in a loop, so can't use break there. What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: Then how do I exit the enclosing block?

Comment: Use `return`. This will exit enclosing method, though. So you might want to place this construct in its own method.

Comment: I have used return in place of break. It is also giving the same error: localjumperror.

Comment: Because you're not in a method :)

Comment: There's an open GitHub issue: [Can't STOP a crawl](https://github.com/chriskite/anemone/issues/24)